# Rotation matrix with center

Tags: math, vector, matrix

How is the center vector calculated in this example or in any example. WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rotate+90+degrees+center+%283%2C0%29

Comment: I did not sleep well. The vector which is added to rotation matrix is (3, -3) how i get this value , i did not pass it.

Answer (score 16):

Homogenous coordinates:

```
            [ cos(theta) -sin(theta) 0 ]
Rotate    = [ sin(theta)  cos(theta) 0 ]
            [      0           0     1 ]

            [ 1 0 x ]
Translate = [ 0 1 y ]
            [ 0 0 1 ]
```

So to perform your transformation, you multiply `Translate(x, y) * Rotate(theta) * Translate(-x, -y)` and get a transformation matrix.

Comment: Did you use the same variable name for the rotation and the x coordinate by accident?

Comment: Shouldn't it be T(x,y)*R*T(-x,-y) ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-and-of-rotation-around-a-point is the question I had about this, the answer states, it has to be the other way round, because it's right to left multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Or in one function statment

```
Vector RotateAbout(Vector node, Vector center, double angle)
{
    return new Vector(
        center.X + (node.X-center.X)*COS(angle) - (node.Y-center.Y)*SIN(angle),
        center.Y + (node.X-center.X)*SIN(angle) + (node.Y-center.Y)*COS(angle)
    };
}
```